# Branch specifier regex in Jenkins scripted pipeline

Tags: regex, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Suppose i want to define pipeline for different branches under same scripted pipeline, how to define the regex for certain pattern of branches. Say for example :-

```html
if(env.BRANCH_NAME ==~ /release.*/){
  stage("Deploy"){
  echo 'Deployed release to QA'
  }
```

Here i want to define that regex in such a way for any branch of the pattern

```html
*release*
```

(meaning any branch with release string in it).
How to achieve that?

And similarly how to achieve something like :-

if the branch is anything but develop, master, release(pattern).

Comment: Thanks a ton. That worked like a charm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using groovy you may use the following

```
if ((env.BRANCH_NAME =~ '.*release.*').matches()) {
    stage("Deploy"){
        echo 'Deployed release to QA'
    }
}
```

And if you want to match any branch name but `develop`, `master` or `release`, you may use [the following regex](https://regex101.com/r/vrFhbU/1/)

```
if ((env.BRANCH_NAME =~ '^((?!develop|master|release).)*$').matches()) {
    stage("Deploy"){
        echo 'Deployed release to QA'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! and how to use that if we want that something like 

if(env.BRANCH_NAME != 'develop' && env.BRANCH_NAME != 'master' && (env.BRANCH_NAME !=~ ".*release.*").matches()) I mean for both = and != condition to match that *release* pattern

Comment: since its a scripted pipeline in jenkins so yes its groovy

Comment: Well, you don't need the two first conditions since `(env.BRANCH_NAME !=~ ".*release.*").matches()` will already cover them.

Comment: actually we have defined separate pipeline for master and develop and release. so  we need an if condition in same file for any branch that is not master, develop and release. so that would mean probably some hotfix or feature branch or anything other than these 3

Comment: currently it gives error as:-
WorkflowScript: 122: expecting ')', found 'if' @ line 122, column 2.
    if(env.BRANCH_NAME != 'develop' && env.BRANCH_NAME != 'master' && (env.BRANCH_NAME !=~ ".*release.*").matches()){
    ^

1 error

 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)

Comment: OK I got it, let me know if the answer is OK now. And please also modify your original post to add your second question to it

Comment: sure thanks ! but jenkins is consistently erroring at :-
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 122: expecting ')', found 'if' @ line 122, column 9.
           if ((env.BRANCH_NAME =~ "^((?!develop|master|release).)*$").matches()) {
           ^

1 error

 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)

Comment: That's strange... Wait I'll check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189979/discussion-between-yassin-hajaj-and-ashley).

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex for matching branch name like `develop`, `release`, `hotfix`.

```
if (branch_name =~ 'develop|hotfix.*|release.*') {

  stage("Deploy") {
        echo 'Deployed release to QA'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

and if you don't use groovy you can do it like below:

```
stage('build') {
        when {
            expression {
                !env.BRANCH_NAME.startsWith('release')
            }
        }
        steps {
            ...
        }
}
```